# Strange behavior while assigning the role programmatically

Tags: users

I used this code to set role to a user :

```
    user_external_login_register($form_state['values']['name'], 'beneficiaire');
    $account = user_external_load($form_state['values']['name']);
    $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
    $account->roles[]= 3;
    user_save($account);
```

My user is weel registered as admin, but if I logout and login, my user has an empty role in addition of the administrator.

Replacing `3` by `administrator` does not fix.

Do you have an idea of what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot `if ( $account !== FALSE )` test, so it is theoretically possible you are not have an user account in `$account` at all.

Comment: thanks for you help @Mołot but it does not fixe :(

Comment: Of course it does not. But please add this check to your code, provide appropriate message if `$account` is false, and then edit your question to tell us that you did it, and that account indeed gets loaded. Or not. That way we'll have at least one of possible reasons eliminated or confirmed.

Comment: @billyJoe $account->roles[3] = "administrator"; See [Programmatically adding and removing roles to users in Drupal](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/programmatically-adding-roles)

Answer (score 0):

This is the roles element in $user object ( $user->roles )

```
roles => array(
  2 => "authenticated user",
  4 => "Site Administrator",
  6 => "Author",
),
```

You must set the user role like:

```
$user->roles[ROLE_ID] = 'ROLE_NAME'
```